# Apex Execution Error: Too many DML rows: 10001

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits

I have a method which is returning Apex Execution Error: Too many DML rows: 10001

```
public void financialAccountforContactAndAccounts(List<Financial_Account_role__c> newFinancialAccountRoles)
        {
            if(!recursivetriggerhelper.isaccessTeamTriggerAccount()){ 
            system.debug('***Entering****');
            Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<ID>();
            Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<ID>();
            Set<Id> accountIdListforAST = new Set<Id>();

            Map<Id,Id> roleIdToTeamId = getRoleToTeamId();
            Map<Id,Id> accountFAcctMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
            List<Financial_Account_Role__c> fARoles = [select Financial_Account__c,contact__c,contact__r.accountid,contact__r.ownerid,contact__r.roleid__c,Organization__c,Organization__r.ownerid, Organization__r.roleid__c from Financial_Account_Role__c where id IN: newFinancialAccountRoles];
            for(Financial_Account_role__c far: fARoles)
            {
                if(far.contact__c != null)
                {
                contactIds.add(far.contact__c); 
                accountFAcctMap.put(far.contact__r.accountid,far.financial_account__c);               
            }
            else if(far.organization__c != null)
            {
                accountIds.add(far.Organization__c);
                accountIdListforAST.add(far.Organization__c);
                accountFAcctMap.put(far.Organization__c,far.financial_Account__c);
            }
        }

        Map<Id,Contact> contactList= new Map<Id,Contact>([select AccountId from Contact where Id IN :contactIds]);

        for(Contact c:contactList.values())
        {
            accountIdListforAST.add(c.accountid);
        }

        List<AccountTeamMember> accountAsts = [select userid,Accountid  from AccountTeamMember where accountid in: accountIdListforAST];

        List<Financial_Account__Share> listFAShares = new List<Financial_Account__Share>(); 
        system.debug('##faroles'+FARoles);
        for(Financial_Account_role__c far: fARoles) 
        {
            system.debug('##newcon'+far.contact__c); 
            system.debug('##newacc'+far.Organization__c);     
            if(far.contact__c!=null)
            {

                 system.debug('****insertFAShare****');
                 Financial_Account__Share faShare = new Financial_Account__Share();
                 faShare.AccessLevel = 'Edit'; 
                 faShare.ParentID = far.Financial_Account__c;
                 faShare.RowCause = Schema.financial_Account__share.RowCause.Manual;
                 faShare.UserOrGroupID = far.contact__r.ownerId;

                 if(far.contact__r.roleid__c !=null && roleIdToTeamId.get(far.contact__r.roleid__c) != null)
                 {
                 Financial_Account__Share faShareForTeam = new Financial_Account__Share();
                 faShareForTeam.AccessLevel = 'Edit'; 
                 faShareForTeam.ParentID = far.Financial_Account__c;
                 faShareForTeam.RowCause = Schema.financial_Account__share.RowCause.Manual;
                 faShareForTeam.UserOrGroupID = roleIdToTeamId.get(far.contact__r.roleid__c);
                 listFAShares.add(faShareForTeam);
                 }

                 for(AccountTeamMember ast: accountAsts)
                 {
                     if(ast.accountid == far.contact__r.accountid)
                     {
                         Financial_Account__Share faShareForATM= new Financial_Account__Share();
                         faShareForATM.AccessLevel = 'Edit'; 
                         faShareForATM.ParentID = far.Financial_Account__c;
                         faShareForATM.RowCause = Schema.financial_Account__share.RowCause.Manual;
                         faShareForATM.UserOrGroupID = ast.userid;
                         listFAShares.add(faShareForATM);
                     }
                 }


                 listFAShares.add(faShare);

            }    
            else if(far.Organization__c!=null)
            {
                //FAShare added for org owner
                 Financial_Account__Share faShare = new Financial_Account__Share();
                 faShare.AccessLevel = 'Edit'; 
                 faShare.ParentID = far.Financial_Account__c;
                 faShare.RowCause = Schema.financial_Account__share.RowCause.Manual;
                 faShare.UserOrGroupID = far.Organization__r.ownerId;

                 //FAShare added for org owner team
                 if((far.Organization__r.roleid__c)!=null && roleIdToTeamId.get(far.Organization__r.roleid__c)!=null)
                 {
                 Financial_Account__Share faShareForTeam = new Financial_Account__Share();
                 faShareForTeam.AccessLevel = 'Edit'; 
                 faShareForTeam.ParentID = far.Financial_Account__c;
                 faShareForTeam.RowCause = Schema.financial_Account__share.RowCause.Manual;
                 faShareForTeam.UserOrGroupID = roleIdToTeamId.get(far.Organization__r.roleid__c);
                 listFAShares.add(faShareForTeam);
                 }

                 for(AccountTeamMember ast: accountAsts)
                 {
                     if(ast.accountid == far.organization__c)
                     {
                         Financial_Account__Share faShareForATM= new Financial_Account__Share();
                         faShareForATM.AccessLevel = 'Edit'; 
                         faShareForATM.ParentID = far.Financial_Account__c;
                         faShareForATM.RowCause = Schema.financial_Account__share.RowCause.Manual;
                         faShareForATM.UserOrGroupID = ast.userid;
                         listFAShares.add(faShareForATM);
                     }
                 }


                 listFAShares.add(faShare);
             } 



        } 
        system.debug('FAShares'+listFAShares);  
        if(listFAShares.size() > 0)
        {
            Database.insert(listFAShares,false);
        }
        }
        recursivetriggerhelper.isaccessTeamTriggerAccount(); 

    }
```

The Last but 1 line Database.insert(listFAShares,false);
That is where i am getting the error.
How do i use Future method here?

Comment: The asynchronous limit for `Total number of records processed as a result of DML statements` is also 10k. Why do you think a `@future` method will help you? Chained `Queueables` might...

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing `Too many DML rows: 10001` error, I'd suggest to use a batch class instead a `@future` method as is noted [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm) (check **Future Method Performance Best Practices** at the bottom of the page in the link). Batch classes let you handle large volume of records and avoid to hit  limits.

For example, if you create a batch class for your code, it would be something like:

```
public class YourBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

       // Logic before to run the query

       String query = 'SELECT Financial_Account__c, contact__c, contact__r.accountid, contact__r.ownerid, ' +
                             'contact__r.roleid__c, Organization__c, Organization__r.ownerid, ' + 
                             'Organization__r.roleid__c ' + 
                      'FROM Financial_Account_Role__c ' + 
                      'WHERE id IN: newFinancialAccountRoles';
       return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){

        List < Financial_Account_Role__c > fARoles = (List < Financial_Account_Role__c >)scope;

        // Logic over fARoles

        List < Financial_Account__Share > listFAShares = new List < Financial_Account__Share > ();
        for (Financial_Account_role__c far: fARoles) {

            // Logic to create objects/modify data

        }

        // finally run DML
        if (listFAShares.size() > 0) {
            Database.insert(listFAShares, false);
        }
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}
```

You run your batch class with:

`Database.executeBatch(new YourBatchClass(), 200)`

Where '200' argument is the number of records that you'll process on per batch. Let's say that your query (Financial_Account_Role__c) returns 10200 records, then the batch class will run 'execute' method 51 times (10200/200 = 51 batches to process). Apex limits are reset for each batch, that ensures that you can process all your records without hitting Apex Limits.

Comment: 10200/200 = 51 batches to process. You beat me to posting my answer so I'll just nitpick yours instead ;)

Comment: Jaja, yikes! you're right, I'll fix it, thanks for the observation.

Comment: It is happening because of Duplicate records added into the List. 
How can i Map listFAShares to check for duplicate values.

Comment: @smohyee I'm surprised you didn't upvote considering it's close to the answer you would have written.

Comment: @AdrianLarson An oversight on my part. It deserves an upvote.